# error: manifest for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:lts not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, dockerhub, aws-devops

I am trying to pull a Jenkins image from docker hub but it is giving me this error:

```
manifest for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:latest not found.
```

I tried using different image and different version specific tag as well but still getting the same issue.

```
[jenkins@localhost jenkins-data]$ docker pull docker.io/jenkins/jenkins
Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository docker.io/jenkins/jenkins ...
manifest for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:latest not found
```

Comment: Did you try with `docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts` ?

Comment: yes i tried that too

Comment: Are you going through a proxy? Are you actually running docker or some other tool that impersonates it?

Comment: proxy settings are disabled. i have installed docker on a VM and i am trying to docker pull from putty using ssh. earlier it was working fine suddenly dont know what went wrong it is now giving me error.

Comment: now the error i am getting is 

```[jenkins@localhost jenkins-data]$ docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠙ jenkins Pulling                                                                                                                                    3.0s
missing signature key```

Comment: Please see [mcve].